# MBtiles and SlippyMap tilenames

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles, slippy

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood how MBTiles and SlippyMap tilenames go together or if there is a problem when I'm doing an export with TileMill.

The issue is that a tile showing the same region - having the same bounding box - is having different tile_column/tile_row in MBtiles and in x/y in OSM.

For example the tile in OSM haves the z/x/y values of **12/2143/1406**. But in my MBTiles file it haves the zoom_level/tile_column/tile_row values **12/2143/2689**.

[image: Tile from MBTiles]
[image: Tile from OSM]

Any idea what is wrong with my export? Or am i misunderstanding naming in MBTiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OSM:
(from: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)

X and Y

```
X goes from 0 (left edge is 180 °W) to 2zoom − 1 (right edge is 180 °E)
Y goes from 0 (top edge is 85.0511 °N) to 2zoom − 1 (bottom edge is 85.0511 °S) in a Mercator projection
```

Meaning OSM uses a NW origin.

Your Mbtiles would be using a SW origin looking at your numbers, but I thought mbtiles follows the XYZ scheme with a NW origin, not the TMS SW origin (see: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/converting-tms-tile-coordinates-to-googlebingosm-tile-coordinates/).

You didn't mention how you were using your tiles, but you will need to use the correct routine for your origin.

Comment: So you're - or better say: the post you linked - suggesting that I can make them interoperable by correcting y in the following way:

var ymax = 1 << zoom;
var y = ymax - y - 1;

Would be great if this works. I'm planning on using the tiles in a custom WebGIS. But it would be really nice if i can address them like OSM as this is already working.

Comment: Maybe instead of "correcting" them, think about using them as is, but utilize a tms routine from your mapping framework.

Might save some headaches later if someone else is maintaining or adding to the tile data.

Comment: Alternately, you could use Mapproxy to convert your mbtiles cache to an OSM cache.  I do this to store Tilemill generated tiles in couchdb -> pouchdb.

Use a XYZ routine to then display the tile layer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
http://rclark.github.io/L.TileGridLayer/example/

use the QGIS TileLayer Plugin and you can add TMS and XYZ reference to your map